# Track SCORM progress offline on Android

Tags: javascript, html, scorm

I am developing a **React Native** application where users can download and play offline **SCORM2004/1.2** courses.

After a course package is written to local filesystem I'm planning on displaying it's **index.html** inside an WebView.

I am looking for a solution to keep track of the progress, score, related metrics on local storage, with no connection to a real LMS.
Should I inject some sort of script into that html file that intercepts scorm calls?